# C for ARM. Binary not recognized

Tags: android, c, arm

I'm trying to cross-compile a simple C program for arm using the
sourcery toolchain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 system("ls");
}

 arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c
 arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip a.out

 $ file a.out    
 a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped
```

Compiles fine, but when I copy it to my android device it's
not recognized as an executable binary. Attempting to run it
gives me "sh: ./test: No such file or directory".

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Android uses a different libc than what the sourcery toolchan uses, you might be able to build a statically linked executable, but you'll be better off using an android toolchain.

Comment: Make this an answer and I'll mark it.  Switching to the ndk toolchain worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5239573/1163019

Comment: Reason it says "No such file..." is because dynamically executable file's loader is missing which boils down to not using android toolchain.